# How to create a regular and smooth surface from a laser scan?

Tags: 3d, coordinates, points, smoothing, geometry-surface

I have done a laser scanning of a rough circular metallic surface. The surface was rotating around one axis while the laser spot acquired the points of the surface moving from the "circumference" towards the axis of rotation.
So the data i have are in practice the cylindrical coordinates of the points acquired by the laser.
My idea is to create a smooth three dimensional representation of the surface. Unfortunately the surface is very rough and has some holes on it, so the data contain many points that don't exist for real due to the reflection of the laser spot and to the holes.

Has anyone an idea on how to filter the points and generate a smooth 3D surface from the data? Is there any mathematical algorithm to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the Ball Pivoting approach: http://vgc.poly.edu/~csilva/papers/tvcg99.pdf